# Python Data Frame Time Delta

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, data-science

I am currently stuck on a problem and figured now is about the time to ask for some help/advice. I currently have a data frame which has a column named Created_On which consists of a DateTime. My goal is to figure out how much time in seconds has passed since the previous row.

I have run the code below but for some reason, the seconds it is giving me are way off. The code below outputs a data frame with an additional column named TimeDiff consisting of the difference in seconds if any.

```
             Created_On                                 
 1. 2014-12-08 03:29:08                    
 2. 2014-12-08 03:29:08                 
 3. 2015-02-09 00:10:01
```

output

```
Time_Diff

 1. 0.0
 2. 0.0
 3. 74453.0
```

Code:

```
Golden['TimeDiff'] = Golden.CREATED_ON.diff().dt.seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you are looking for [Series.dt.total_seconds()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
In [45]: Golden['TimeDiff'] = Golden.CREATED_ON.diff().dt.total_seconds()

In [46]: Golden
Out[46]:
           CREATED_ON   TimeDiff
0 2014-12-08 03:29:08        NaN
1 2014-12-08 03:29:08        0.0
2 2015-02-09 00:10:01  5431253.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, on the code and the format. I will use it as a prime example on my next code reference.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.seconds.html

```
pandas.Series.dt.seconds
Series.dt.seconds
Number of seconds (>= 0 and *less than 1 day*) for each element.
```

[emphasis added]

This takes the number of seconds modulo the number of seconds in a day. So in this case, it is giving you the difference between 00:10:01 and 03:29:08 of the previous day, which is 74453.0 seconds.